# Issue in playing youtube video in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, youtube

I am trying to play youtube video within my application. Here is the code I am using

```
- (void)embedYouTube:(NSString*)url frame:(CGRect)frame {  
 NSString* embedHTML = @"\ 
    <html><head>\ 
 <style type=\"text/css\">\ 
 body {\ 
 background-color: transparent;\ 
 color: white;\ 
 }\ 
 </style>\ 
 </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\ 
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \ 
 width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\ 
    </body></html>";  
 NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, url, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];  
 if(videoView == nil) {  
   videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];  
   [self.view addSubview:videoView];  
 }  
 [videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];  
}
```

Video is getting played nicely. But after video is played

1. I am taken back to the root view controller not to the view from
   which the above function is called.
2. Also in the root view controller the view is not active.  I cant
   click any buttons in that view.
3. Also I can see a empty space of 20px at the bottom of view,it seems
   like the view is occupying the space of status bar

How can I do it properly in ios?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have same problem before.

Just make custom class for Uiwebview without .xib file and implement your code.

And just make object of custom class in view you want to play video.

But don't add it to that view just make object and pass video url.

Comment: If possible could you please give me a sample code or example? this is what i did @interface YouTubeViewer : UIWebView 
{
}

- (YouTubeViewer *)initWithStringAsURL:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame;

end and from I am calling like this.   YouTubeViewer *yt = [[YouTubeViewer alloc] init];

Comment: I have sent code to you by email, one more thing this code working fine for iphone only not for ipad if possible then help me for that...

Comment: Thanks for the code, for me the issue was rectified when I changed to navigation view controller after seeing your code. I will have a look and see whether I can play it in ipad